# sum of sales per postal code group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query where you can see all the sales of a person divided in postal groups. But now I want to have the sum of all the sales per postal group.

I have the query like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.LastName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostalCode 
                       ORDER BY SUM(s.SalesYTD) DESC) AS 'Row Number',
    CAST(s.SalesYTD AS INT) SalesYTD, 
    a.PostalCode
FROM 
    Sales.SalesPerson s
INNER JOIN 
    Person.Person p ON s.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN 
    Person.Address a ON a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY 
    p.LastName, a.PostalCode,s.SalesYTD;
--WHERE TerritoryID IS NOT NULL
--AND SalesYTD <> 0
```

But how to manage the total of each postal group?

Thank you

This is the ouput:

```
LastName    Row Number  SalesYTD    PostalCode
Mitchell    1   4251369 98027
Blythe  2   3763178 98027
Carson  3   3189418 98027
Reiter  4   2315186 98027
Vargas  5   1453719 98027
Ansman-Wolfe    6   1352577 98027
Jiang   7   559698  98027
Pak 1   4116871 98055
Varkey Chudukatil   2   3121616 98055
Saraiva 3   2604541 98055
Ito 4   2458536 98055
Valdez  5   1827067 98055
Mensa-Annan 6   1576562 98055
Campbell    7   1573013 98055
Tsoflias    8   1421811 98055
Alberts 9   519906  98055
Abbas   10  172524  98055
```

So how to get the total of salesYTD of postal code: 98027?

Thank you

Comment: I am using MIcrosoft sql server 2014

Comment: Group by `PostalCode` only and `SELECT` `SUM()` of Sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get sales per postal code just:

```
SELECT PostalCode, SUM(SalesYTD) AS 'Summary sales'
FROM Sales.SalesPerson s
INNER JOIN Person.Person p ON s.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.Address a ON a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY a.PostalCode
```

If you want sales of particular `PostalCode` you can even do it that way:

```
SELECT SUM(SalesYTD) AS 'Summary sales'
FROM Sales.SalesPerson s
INNER JOIN Person.Person p ON s.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.Address a ON a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID
WHERE PostalCode = 98027
```